# EOS Token contract audit issue

Tags: smart-contract

My token contract was done by a third party vendor that did not share source code of the token contract with me. Can you help me on how to find the code, so that I can submit it to you for audit purpose?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get source code from compiled code, as the process is one way and destructive.

Contact your vendor and ask him to provide the source code for you.